# Cloudwatch Insights for Kubernetes Failed pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I recently started monitoring our Kubernetes cluster using Cloudwatch monitoring agents. But I am unable to get the monitoring done for a couple of very important metrics.

- Number of Failed pods per deployment
- Number of Failed pods per Namespace
- Number of Failed pods per Cluster

Pod failure is the basic unit that needs to be monitored and I am unable to get this done through AWS Cloudwatch. I was referring to [Container Insights Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-EKS.html), And nothing mentioned there. Are there any way I can configure the Cloudwatch agent to capture these metrics.

**Edit: More information after researching**

There are few issues raised against AWS Container Monitoring.

- https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/38
- https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/120
- https://github.com/cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch

Looks like aws is a way behind all other wrt to Kubernetes ecosystem.